# How can I map and use stored procedure in Entity Framework 6 by code first way?

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I have an ASP.NET MVC project and I want to use Entity Framework 6 code-first. In Entity Framework 6, we can use stored procedures and map to them. I use this code for mapping it but when I want create my database I get this error:

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

But when I clean all stored procedure mappings, it creates my database.

I have to use stored procedures in my program, for this reason I have to know how can I map and use stored procedures by EF 6 code-first? And what's wrong in my code and how can I call my stored procedures when I am mapping them?

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Raja.Models.Context
{
    public class RajaContext : DbContext
    {
        public RajaContext() : base("name=RajaContext")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            #region SpareParts
            modelBuilder.Entity<Spareparts>()
                        .MapToStoredProcedures(s => s.Update(u => u.HasName("Spareparts_Update").Parameter(P => P.Code, "Code")
               .Parameter(P => P.SparepartName, "SparepartName")
               .Parameter(P => P.Serial, "Serial")
               .Parameter(P => P.ProjectNumber, "ProjectNumber")
               .Parameter(P => P.SparePartType, "SparePartType")
               .Parameter(P => P.Emplacement, "Emplacement")
               //.Parameter(P => P.TakingPlace.TrainID, "TakingPlace")
               .Parameter(P => P.AssemblyTime, "AssemblyTime")
               .Parameter(P => P.ConsumptionFactor, "ConsumptionFactor")
               .Parameter(P => P.Warranty, "Warranty")
               .Parameter(P => P.Qty, "Qty")
               .Parameter(P => P.Cost, "Cost")
               .Parameter(P => P.HasRepair, "HasRepair")
               .Parameter(P => P.Enable, "Enable")
               .Parameter(P => P.Picture, "Picture")
               .Parameter(P => P.Description, "Description")
               .Parameter(P => P.CreatedDate, "CreatedDate")
               .Parameter(P => P.CreateByUser, "CreateByUser")
               .Parameter(P => P.LastModificationDate, "LastModificationDate")
               .Parameter(P => P.LastModifyByUser, "LastModifyByUser")
               .Parameter(P => P.PlaceOfSupply, "PlaceOfSupply"))
                                                     .Delete(d => d.HasName("Spareparts_Delete").Parameter(p => p.SparepartId, "SparepartId"))
                                                     .Insert(i => i.HasName("Spareparts_Insert").Parameter(P => P.SparepartName, "SparepartName")
               .Parameter(P => P.Code, "Code")
               .Parameter(P => P.Serial, "Serial")
               .Parameter(P => P.ProjectNumber, "ProjectNumber")
               .Parameter(P => P.SparePartType, "SparePartType")
               .Parameter(P => P.Emplacement, "Emplacement")
               //.Parameter(P => P.TakingPlace.TrainID, "TakingPlace")
               .Parameter(P => P.AssemblyTime, "AssemblyTime")
               .Parameter(P => P.ConsumptionFactor, "ConsumptionFactor")
               .Parameter(P => P.Warranty, "Warranty")
               .Parameter(P => P.Qty, "Qty")
               .Parameter(P => P.Cost, "Cost")
               .Parameter(P => P.HasRepair, "HasRepair")
               .Parameter(P => P.Enable, "Enable")
               .Parameter(P => P.Picture, "Picture")
               .Parameter(P => P.Description, "Description")
               .Parameter(P => P.CreatedDate, "CreatedDate")
               .Parameter(P => P.CreateByUser, "CreateByUser")
               .Parameter(P => P.LastModificationDate, "LastModificationDate")
               .Parameter(P => P.LastModifyByUser, "LastModifyByUser")
               .Parameter(P => P.PlaceOfSupply, "PlaceOfSupply")));
            #endregion
        }

        public DbSet<Spareparts> Spareparts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe it's trainId causing the issue, the name should match or you have to manually map it. Also you need to decorate the Id property with the [key] attribute if that the primary key

Comment: as  you can see trainid is comment .and how can i manually map it?

Comment: what?? can you explain i don't know what you say correctly

Comment: see there i use this link for mapping SP http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20First%20Insert%2fUpdate%2fDelete%20Stored%20Procedure%20Mapping

Comment: You will need to use EDMX file then got to mapping section and select it from the drops own